# ¿Se pueden enviar variables de estilo por JS a SheetJs para que la tabla creada en excel tenga bordes?

Tags: javascript, css, sheetjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo que toma una tabla html y la exporta a excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.10.3/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
            <script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
            <style>
                    .borde{
                            border: 1px solid #000000;
                    }
                    .center{
                            text-align: center;
                    }
            </style>

            <table id="mytable" class="center">
                    <tr class="borde">
                            <td class="borde">ID</td>
                            <td class="borde">NOMBRE</td>
                            <td class="borde">APELLIDO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="borde">
                            <td class="borde">1</td>
                            <td class="borde">Hola</td>
                            <td class="borde">Chau</td>
                    </tr>
            </table><br>

            <button id="button-a">Create Excel</button>

            <script>
                    var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(document.getElementById('mytable'), {sheet:"Sheet JS"});
                    var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
                    function s2ab(s) {
                                    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
                                    var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
                                    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
                                    return buf;
                    }
                    $("#button-a").click(function(){
                    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), 'reporte.xlsx');
                    });
            </script>
```

La tabla se exporta asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero saber es si en el mismo script que crea la tabla puedo pasarle variables para que la tabla que se cree tenga bordes en los tr y td, con otros procesos como excelphp podia hacerlo pero aca no me sale y  no encuentro algo relacionado.
Y que la tabla quede asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta característica solo está disponible en la versión *Pro* (pagada) de SheetJS.

Lo indican en su documentación https://docs.sheetjs.com/ (traducido):

> Esta es la versión *community*.  También ofrecemos una versión *pro* con mejoras en el rendimiento, caracteríscas adicionales como **estilos** y soporte dedicado:

Comment: Que bajon, probe recien sumar esto y puedo ponerle tamaño a las celdas creadas en el excel por eso pense que podia meterle bordes tambien: wb["Sheets"]["Sheet JS"]["!cols"] = [{ wpx : 100 },{ wpx : 150 }];